# Should I use "like" or "likes" with "some"?

Tags: word-choice, subject-verb-agreement

Which one of the following would be correct?

- Some **likes** ice-cream, some don't.
- Some **like** ice-cream, some don't.

As of what I know, we use "likes" with singular words like "He, she" etc and we use "like" with plural words like "they" etc. 
However, I am confused about this one. What will we use with "some"?

Comment: Treat *some* as plural: "Some **like** ice cream ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think of *some* as *some people*, who like or don't like things.

> Some (people) like ice-cream, others don't.

*Some* is not used with a singular noun, we say "a boy, a man",etc. The word "people" is left out in your sentences, but if you put it after *some*, you will see that your first example is incorrect.

Comment: How would you explain this: "There is some guy at the gate."

Comment: @SovereignSun That's different. Here we have several people in mind, whereas your example has another meaning of "a certain person", unknown to us.

Comment: *Some* is used to refer to a particular person or thing without stating exactly which one:
Some lucky person will win more than $1,000,000 in the competition